# How can I link a label and text field together using GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, grid-layout, gridbaglayout

I'm trying all I can to move my text fields and labels around my panel to get them in a good position so it looks neat. I want my label, right next to my text field.

However, I can only achieve this by altering GridBagConstraints.gridx/gridy and even then I still can't get them side by side and it's really frustrating me.

Is there any code that will attach these two components side by side without having to always alter the gridx/gridy numbers?

Here's my code:

```
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
            gbc.gridy--;
            add(new JLabel("Serial: "), gbc);
            //gbc.gridy--;
            add(new JLabel("Location: "), gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 10;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            add(new JTextField(10), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(new JTextField(10), gbc);
```

It would be ideal if I could move both the labels and text fields around by altering one line of code or even one number. How can I achieve this, or something similar.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The easiest way, would be add the text field and label to the same panel with a flowLayout or a gridLayout(2,0) and then move around just the panel

Comment: I have no idea how to code that, sorry.

Comment: oracle has some nice tutorials about layouts [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html)

Answer (score 1):

The label/field use case is a pretty common one.  The cleanest way to code for it is by taking advantage of GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE, which just happens to be the default value for gridx and gridy, and GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER.

When both gridx and gridy are GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE, the added component is placed on the same row, as if gridx were being incremented and gridy were unchanged—however, if gridwidth is GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER, the *next* component added will be placed on a new row, assuming gridx and gridy are still RELATIVE.

```
JTextField serialField = new JTextField(10);
JTextField locationField = new JTextField(10);

JLabel serialLabel = new JLabel("Serial: ");
serialLabel.setLabelFor(serialField);

JLabel locationLabel = new JLabel("Location: ");
locationLabel.setLabelFor(locationField);

GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.BASELINE_LEADING;
gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);

gbc.gridwidth = 1;
add(serialLabel, gbc);
gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
add(serialField, gbc);

gbc.gridwidth = 1;
add(locationLabel, gbc);
gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
add(locationField, gbc);
```

The `gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;` line tells the GridBagLayout “this component should be treated as the last one on the line” (while gridx and gridy are RELATIVE).

Of course, if you set gridx and gridy to actual (nonnegative) numbers, you will override the automatic functionality of RELATIVE and REMAINDER.  But why make it more difficult than it needs to be?